# load content form wordpress with phonegap

Tags: android, wordpress, cordova

i spend a lot of time searching how to load content form `wordpress` into my app built with `phonegap`.
I have installed everything to start but i'm stuck with this:

```
$(function(){
            $.ajax({
                url: 'http://ultravoz.org/api/get_recent_posts/',
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(data){
                    var source   = $("#blog-template").html();
                    var blogData = template(data);
                    $('#blog-data').html(blogData);
                    $('#blog-data').trigger('create');
                    dfd.resolve(data);

                },
                error: function(data){
                    console.log(data);
                }
            });
        });
```

and the message:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://ultravoz.org/api/get_recent_posts/. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.
```

thanks!!!